# Is there any verify method to verify a signature in Tezos?

Tags: tezos-client, tezos-signer

The `tezos-client` provides a `sign` method to sign a message in bytes using the private key and returns the signature.

Is there any method like `verify` which takes the message, the signature and the public key to verify that it is signed by the user who holds the private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find in this *Repl* **how to check user signature in JavaScript**:

I also added an *example*, just *run* it and you'll get the result.

https://repl.it/@DalyIng/verifyTezosSignature

Comment: Thanks, Daly it worked like a charm. Can you please also add a script to sign the message in Tezos?

Comment: @ShubhamChadokar,  Here is the script to sign an operation on Tezos:

https://repl.it/@DalyIng/signOperationTezos

Comment: Thank you @Daly for all your help.

Comment: if you rather use the octez-client (tezos-client) then the answer by @cousinit is the correct one.
also ideally all SE answers should be self-contained, not requiring access to external resources.

Answer (score 1):

```
check that <bytes> was signed by <key> to produce <signature> [-q --quiet]
```

Check the signature of a byte sequence as per Michelson instruction `CHECK_SIGNATURE`.

bytes: the signed data

key: existing public_key alias

signature: the signature to check

-q --quiet: Use only exit codes

Comment: I think this requires a Smart contract with Check_signature function. Is there anything available in tezos-client?

Comment: This is the correct answer to this specific question, as tezos-client (now octez-client) does provide this utility. It can both sign and verify signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Taquito provides [Validation functions](https://tezostaquito.io/docs/validators) including a signature validator.